# CentOS 6 - libstdc++ no such file or directory?

Tags: c++, centos

I'm trying to execute a game server, and whenever I do I receive the following error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have absolutely no direction on what to do next. I really hope I can receive some help.

Comment: `file` and `ldd` say...?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ldd_%28Unix%29

Comment: ldd:
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77c8000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf77be000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf77a3000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => not found
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf7779000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => not found
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf75e1000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77c9000)

Comment: The only package I was able to install did not fix my issue.

Comment: Could you please give more details about your environment and the way (script) you start the server?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Install the 32-bit LibC++.

```
yum install libstdc++.i686
```

Comment: my system is 64 bit.. how to solve for that..??

Comment: I'm presuming this is actually a 64-bit specific fix, otherwise he would just say "Install LibC++".